# Value of sum from thrust::reduce not correct

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia, hpc, thrust

I have been trying to implement some code requiring to call reduce on thrust::device_ptr, and the results are not consistent with CPU implementation while dealing with large values. I have to deal with large values. So is there a way around:

My code:

```
    #include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <thrust/host_vector.h>
    #include <thrust/device_vector.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #define   NZ  412//
    #define   NX  402//
    using namespace std;
    using real =double;
    
    
    void allocate_array_2d(real**& preal, const int dim1, const int dim2) {
        // Contiguous allocation of 2D arrays
    
        preal = new real * [dim1];
        preal[0] = new real[dim1 * dim2];
        for (int i = 1; i < dim1; i++) preal[i] = preal[i - 1] + dim2;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
                preal[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    #define cudaCheckError(code)                                             \
      {                                                                      \
        if ((code) != cudaSuccess) {                                         \
          fprintf(stderr, "Cuda failure %s:%d: '%s' \n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
                  cudaGetErrorString(code));                                 \
        }                                                                    \
      }
    
    
    int main()
    
    {
        real** a;
        std::cout.precision(30);
        allocate_array_2d(a, NZ, NX);//input array
       
        for (int i = 0; i < NZ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NX; j++) {
                a[i][j] = 2.14748e+09;
              
              
            }
        }
    
            real* da;
            cudaCheckError(cudaMalloc(&da, NZ * NX  * sizeof(real)));
            cudaCheckError(cudaMemcpy(da,a[0], NZ * NX  * sizeof(real),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    
            ///************************
            //CUDA KERNELS ARE HERE
            // REMOVED FOR CLEAR QUESTION
            ///*************************
      
            real sum1=0;
          
            thrust::device_ptr<real> dev_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(da);
            sum1 = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+NZ*NX, 0, thrust::plus<real>());
            
            cout<<" \nsum gpu "<< sum1<<"\n";
    
            real sum2=0;
    
            ////////CPU PART DOING SAME THING//////
            for (int i = 0; i < NZ; i++) {
    
                for (int j = 0; j < NX; j++) {
                   sum2 += a[i][j];
                    
                }
            }
    
    
            cout<<"\nsum cpu "<< sum2<<"\n";
            if((sum2-sum1)<0.001)
            std::cout << "\nSUCESS "<< "\n";
            else
            std::cout << "\nFailure & by "<<sum2-sum1<< "\n";
       
    }
```

The compiler that I am using is nvcc and my graphics card is nvidia 1650 with compute capability 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions_ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b.html#ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b), thrust expects the type for summation to be reflected in the `init` value:

```
sum1 = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+NZ*NX, 0, thrust::plus<real>());
                                              ^
```

The type of that constant you have is an integral type.  If you change that to a double-precision constant:

```
sum1 = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+NZ*NX, 0.0, thrust::plus<real>());
```

you get matching results, between CPU and GPU, according to my testing.  (You could alternatively cast your constant to `real` type: `(real)0` and use that, and there are other ways to address this as well, such as dropping the use of the init value and the binary op.)